# Filtering on dataframes by equality on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter through a dataframe in python of 3 columns. I want only the rows for which the first two columns are the same but not the third one. i.e.

0. A B C
1. 1 4 2
2. 1 5 3
3. 2 3 3
4. 3 1 1
5. 4 3 2
6. 2 3 5

On the above example, I would like to get only rows 3 and 6 since the first two columns match.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df[['A', 'B']].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
2  2  3  3
5  2  3  5
```